# Nuxt, localhost refused to connect, strapi application works

Tags: vue.js, localhost, nuxt.js, strapi

*emphasized text*I have trouble to connect to localhost. I am trying to run Nuxt aplication on port 3000.

`sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` command says that my port is listening.

My other strapi application works on port 1337.
I tried to change port of Nuxt application but didn't work out. I have tried different browsers and remove cache. Application worked yesterday and I am not aware that I have changed something. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Solved. Colleague added serverMiddleware: ['redirect-ssl'] packege to project that caused problems on localhost.

Comment: i have the same serverMiddleware redirect and my port 1337 for strapi won’t load on nuxt 2.6 can this middleware also be the case?